# How to make a drive mounted in terminal appear on GUI?

Tags: linux, mount, gui, ntfs

I had a NTFS formatted drive that when plugged in, the system automatically mounted to read-only so I had to use the terminal.

```
mkdir /mnt/newntfsdrive
mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda3 /mnt/newntfsdrive
```

Now the drive is mounted but it does not appear on GUI. How can I make the newly mounted drive accessible from GUI?

Comment: If default is read only, you need to turn Windows fast start up off which sets hibernation flag. When flag is set Linux NTFS driver will only mount read only to prevent damage. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation